# How to delay a ROS Topic by a certain amount of time

Tags: python, ros, subscriber

**Actual problem:**

I have a controller node that subscribes to 2 topics and publishes to 1 topic. Although, in simulation everything seems to be working as expected, in actual HW, the performance degrades. I suspect the problem is that one of the two input topics is lagging behind the other one by a significant amount of time.

**Question:**

I want to re-create this behavior in simulation in order to test the robustness of the controller. Therefore, I need to delay one of the topics by a certain amount of time - ideally this should be configurable parameter. I could write a node that has a FIFO memory buffer and adjust the delay-time by monitoring the frequency of the topic. Before I do that, is there a [command line tool](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_delay) or any other quick to implement method that I can use?

P.s. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS-Kinetic.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any out of the box solutions that would do exactly what you describe here.

For a quick hack, if your topic does not have a timestamp and the node just takes in the messages as they arrive the easiest thing to do would be to record a bag and play the two topics back from two different instances of `rosbag play`. Something like this:

```
first terminal
rosbag play mybag.bag --clock --topics /my/topic
second terminal started some amount of time later
rosbag play mybag.bag --topics /my/other_topic
```

Not sure about the `--clock` flag, whether you need it depends mostly on what you mean by simulation. If you would want to control the time difference more than pressing enter in two different terminals you could write a small bash script to launch them.

---

Another option that would still involve bags, but would give you more control over the exact time the message is delayed by would be to edit the bag to have the messages in the bag already with the correct delay. Could be done relatively easily by modifying the first example in the [rosbag cookbook](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook#Rewrite_bag_with_header_timestamps):

```
import rosbag

with rosbag.Bag('output.bag', 'w') as outbag:
    for topic, msg, t in rosbag.Bag('input.bag').read_messages():
        # This also replaces tf timestamps under the assumption 
        # that all transforms in the message share the same timestamp
        if topic == "/tf" and msg.transforms:
            outbag.write(topic, msg, msg.transforms[0].header.stamp)
        else:
            outbag.write(topic, msg, msg.header.stamp if msg._has_header else t)
```

Replacing the if else with:

```
...
import rospy
...

if topic == "/my/other_topic":
    outbag.write(topic, msg, t + rospy.Duration.from_sec(0.5))
else:
    outbag.write(topic, msg, t)
```

Should get you most of the way there.

---

Other than that if you think the node would be useful in the future or you want to have it work on live data as well then you would need to implement the the node you described with some queue. One thing you could look at for inspiration could be the [topic tools](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools), git for [topic tools source](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/tree/noetic-devel/tools/topic_tools/src).